# Pusher notifications not triggering in laravel

Tags: laravel, pusher

I created a new event, and signed up at pusher in order to test my notifications.

This is how my controller looks like:

```
public function view_posts(){
    $user = User::find(6999);
    event(new TestNotification($user));
    return $user;       
}
```

And inside the TestNotification I initialized my constructor:

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class TestNotification implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $user;

    public function __construct($user)
    {
        //
        $this->user = $user;
    }


    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('channel-name');
    }
}
```

I have my .env setup. ( All the details are fake )

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
QUEUE_DRIVER=database

PUSHER_APP_NAME=testapp
PUSHER_APP_ID=2655265
PUSHER_APP_KEY=ffgf5ghfgh1g5
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=6rergf4erg4er
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=us2
```

When I visit my url, the user gets returned, fine, but when I go to pusher console, I don't see the user array or anything related to the notification.

Note: If I change my broadcast_driver to log, it doesn't work either

Is there anything that I am possibly missing?

Comment: are you running the worker? `php artisan queue:work`

Comment: No am not. How does that make any difference?

Comment: yes you'll need to have that running to process the queue